# A set of Hymns in Taittiriya Samhita of Krishna Yajur Veda

Tags: yajur-veda, krishna-yajurveda, taittiriya-aranyaka

Can any expert here, provide me the meanings of mantras ending with "Swaha..." in the Samhita
of Taittiriya Shakha of the Krishna Yajur Veda? I meant, in the samhita there are mantras, like-

`krishnaaya swaha, swetayaa swaha, lalaataaya swaha, lalaamaya swaha mastishkaaya swaaha , aakekasaabhya swaha ...bhasate swaha Valadhaanaya swaha ..retasse swahaa..` etc..

Can any gurus please enlighten when and where its chanting. Does it signifies that, this can be chanted  only in front of Yajna or we can chant it anytime.

Also please share me the source and link where can I find the e-book of this Samhita and this particular section.